# How to test that observations are related to time?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, time-varying-covariate

I have a vector of observations (call it $Y$) and a vector of corresponding time (call it $T$). I want to test whether the change of observations are related to time. The errors here are i.i.d and mean is 0.

Is there any method or test can do this? I guess I can try polynomial regression and then do the full model F-test. Is this a reasonable way to do this? Can you give me any other suggestions to do this? Please also give me any assumptions about the observations, $H_0$ and test required by your method.

Comment: About what errors do we talk here? What do you mean by 'change of observation'?

Comment: We can assume the error here is $Normal(0,\sigma^2)$, and they are iid. I want to check is there any relation between the time and observations. I mean the observation is the a function of time. For example, y=f(t)+$\epsilon$,where $\epsilon$ is the error term.

Comment: Okay. In this case, your suggestion sounds fine. A flexible alternative would be to fit a natural cubic spline and test by a partial F test the null hypothesis of constant f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could try the durbin watson test : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Watson_statistic